# Стоит ли использовать Spring с Kotlin

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, kotlin

Интересует вопрос, совместимы ли Java ee спецификации и Spring с Kotlin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kotlin интероперабелен с библиотеками, написанными на Java. Это одна из его сильных сторон. Поэтому его можно использовать с тем же, с чем вы используете Java.
А в новом [Spring Framework 5.0](https://spring.io/blog/2017/01/04/introducing-kotlin-support-in-spring-framework-5-0) уделили особое внимание поддержке языка Kotlin, учли его особенности, чтобы повысить продуктивность разработки в связке Spring + Kotlin.

Comment: А как обстоит вопрос с jax-rs

Comment: @JNat вот нашёл пример jax-rs + kotlin https://moelholm.com/2017/03/16/javaee-helloworld-kotlin/
как буду возле пк, может, подробнее напишу

Comment: а как котлин совместим с concurency, к примеру тот же CompletableFuture из 8

Comment: @JMas это новый вопрос, я в этом не копенгаген. Рекомендую прошерстить stackoverflow в поиске похожего вопроса, а если не найдёте - задать свой.